# How can I remove space between Footnode and Text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, formatting, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013

I have a friend, who is writing a homework for their studies. She has a problem, that the max lenght of text, sould be 20 pages. We are now trying to reduce the pages ;)

We have the following foot note:

[image: Foot Note]

I have marked with an red arrow a big gap.

Why is this gap even here? How can I remove it?

I would like to place the line straight below the text, so that we do not loose any kind of space.

Comment: a) added space after each paragraph, b) padding before signature. Both can be removed. Delete the signature. Remove new line characters after *`schung.` and use `Shift`+`Enter` instead to make soft break to new line. Add your text and then signature. Should be fine this way.